# Entity Framework Self Join & Child Objects

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using Entity Framework in .net 4.0, how do you set up an entity for the object below?

I have an item that people can comment on and then people can comment on comments and so on

Ex:

Item
-Comment
--Comment
--Comment
---Comment
-Comment
-Comment
--Comment

My current table structure in sql:

### Comments

ID (int)
ParentCommentID (int)
ProductID (string)
Title 
Text

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good idea would be to check out the [Stack Overflow Creative Commons Data Dump.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/)

They have a similar setup for post/comments, so you can see how they setup their schema. Hanselman also has a blog post on a OData service for it [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx), so you can check out his EDMX.

Your on the right track though:

- Item 1..* Comments
- Comment 1..* Comments

You'll need to setup *ParentCommentID* as self-referencing FK, then when you import that into your EDMX Entity Framework should model it correctly. You might need to rename the nabigational property to something more meaninful.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the info, I had to have tried this 5 different ways and it wasn't working, I went back with the same table schema as above following Hanselman's post and it worked first try. I must have just missed a step some where.